# Paypal IPN setup

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

After a few hours of trying to fix paypal IPN I am back in the start. It is very frustrating but I can't understan this. I have a form and sends it to paypal but I don't know how to go further afterwords. This is as far as I have got

```
echo '<form method="post" action="'; 
include("settings.php");

if($_POST['payment_buy_ads'] == 'PayPal' && $paypal_status == 1){
echo 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
}
if($_POST['payment_buy_ads'] == 'Payza' && $payza_status == 1){
 echo '';
}
if($_POST['payment_buy_ads'] == 'Perfect_Money' && $perfect_money_status == 1){
echo '';
}
echo '">';
echo '
```

```
<h3>Website URL</h3>
<input type="url" class="form-control" id="user_url" name="url" placeholder="Whats the URL of the website?" required />
<br>
<h3>Ad Pack Type</h3>
<p class="col-lg-12 ">Chose how many ad credits do you like to buy?</p>
<br>
<br> 
<select name="amount" class="form-control">
<option value="'.$cost_p_1.'">1000 hits - $'.$cost_p_1.'</option><option value="'.$cost_p_2.'">5000 hits - $'.$cost_p_2.'</option><option value="'.$cost_p_3.'">20000 hits - $'.$cost_p_3.'</option><option value="'.$cost_p_4.'">100000 hits - $'.$cost_p_4.'</option><option value="'.$cost_p_5.'">1000000 hits - $'.$cost_p_5.'</option></select><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.$paypal_email.'">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Full Page Link Advertising">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="user_email" value="'.$_SESSION['email'].'">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="notify_url" value="'.$site_link.'/ipn.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Create New Ad">

<br>
<br>
'; include("settings.php");
echo '
<br>


<br>
<br>

</form>
```

This works perfectly to get to paypal checkout but how do I check afterwords that the payment was successfully and which package users choosed.

Please explain step by step and try to keep it as simple as you can

Regards,
Oliver

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to where you can turn on ipn in Paypal and set the url for paypal to communicate with you.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ipn listener.

You need to tell Paypal what web page to send messages to and in your `ipn listener` php page you receive the information you're looking for.

Paypal communicates directly with your server - there is no browser involved. The only way to see what is going on is to log the activity. You can test the process using the sandbox. All this is explained in his tutorial.

In your account settings, there is a place to set up ipn and it you can enter the "ipn handler url" (the address of your listener page).

**UPDATE** This link will allow you to set up you [IPN settings](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify)